# Reproduce local video file using XAML and C++

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, uwp

I am currently making a Windows Universal App starting with an Kinect SDK application called CameraFrames. It's a rather complex app but I am having trouble with playing a video from my local files.

To do this, in one of the main windows of my app I insert a MediaPlayerElement in XAML:

```
        <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="_MediaPlayerElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0"/>
```

[image]

As shown in the captur above. Below the XAML file I have a cpp file and a header file. I tried searching on the web for a solution to my problem but couldn't find any. It's my first time using XAML thus I don't know how to connect the different objects that I put on my UI to actual code. The ideal result would be to have the ability to choose from my computer which video file I want to reproduce and then display it on this MediaPlayerElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.source) property of your MediaPlayerElement.

If you want to do that in code, use [MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromstoragefile) or [CreateFromStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.createfromstream) method to create the media source.

Also, UWP apps run in isolated containers. By design, they can’t access files from arbitrary location of your hard drive. Read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/) for more info.